# Access local_tmp from a playbook

Tags: ansible

I've been setting the destination path of every temporary files I have to download. For instance:

```
- name: Downloading file
  uri:
    url: "{{url}}"
    dest: ~/.ansible/tmp/
```

Is there any way of reading the configuration variable `local_tmp` (and `remote_tmp`) from within the playbook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>I'm not sure why you'd want to place the temporary files under `local_tmp`/`remote_tmp` directories handled by Ansible.</sup>

There is a module called [`tempfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/tempfile_module.html) which allows you to create a temporary directory under the path specified in system temporary directory:

```
- name: Ensure a temporary directory for download exists
  tempfile:
    state: directory
    suffix: my_download
  register: temp_dir

- name: Ensure a file is downloaded from {{ url }}
  uri:
    url: "{{ url }}"
    dest: "{{ temp_dir.path }}"
```

and if you want to persist the name across the playbook runs, just create a subdirectory in `lookup('env', 'TMPDIR') | default('/tmp')` for local, or `ansible_env.TMPDIR | default('/tmp')` for remote.

Comment: That's seems to be what I was looking for:
ansible_env.TMPDIR | default('/tmp')
But the module tempfile seems to be the way to go. I didn't know it before now. Really appreciate.